# Migrating /home to a new PC

Tags: backup, restore, migration

I have built a new PC and installed Kubuntu 20.04.1.

I always keep the `/home` partition on a dedicated drive, so normally when upgrading hardware, I just migrate that drive across to the new box and install the OS. This time, however, I have gone with 2 new hard drives, one of which is, as usual, a dedicated `/home` partition. Which leads me onto my question(s) - presumably, I can use a command like `rsync` to back my existing `/home` partition up onto an external HDD and then "restore" to the `/home` partition on my new box?

Is this the simplest and/or the best way to do this?
What options do I need to pass to the `rsync` command?
Can I do it while logged in, or do I need to do it from a USB boot?
Do I need to run it as root (using `sudo`)?
What things do I need to watch out for when carrying out this process?
Anything else I have missed?

Comment: Congratulations upon the new box! Are you comfortable opening the box to temporarily attach the old HDD? Or do you want to do everything via USB?

Comment: I usually just copy everything onto a USB disk, and then copy it back to the new system. Done.

Comment: I used rsync to copy my /home to my laptop, but not everything updated. I think it was the date settings & some files in new install had newer date. I had previously done a test install of Kubuntu on sdb, liked it, so installed on NVMe drive & use cp -a to copy /home to new install. That seemed to work better.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I'm OK with the hardware side, I always build / upgrade the hardware myself. I am however not overly familiar with the nuts and bolts of Linux, mainly due to lack of time to play with it, although installation is not a problem, nor is installing app and other day-to-day tasks. It sounds like it should be fairly easy to back up my home directory using Dolphin file manager then and just copy onto the new box using using the same method. Will this also copy all the hidden files that remember settings, browser history, etc.?

Comment: Think I've got it now. If I use cp -a it will copy the entire tree in one hit and I can just reverse it at the other end. To preserve file attributes (incl permissions) I need to format my USB HDD at ext4. Provding I have the same user name on both machines, I assume I will not have any file "ownership" issues. Am I correct?

Comment: You might want to also check out Clonezilla, if you're more comfortable with a handy GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any method to copy your `/home` to a new destination.  There should be nothing under `/home` that needs to be installed.

It should be sufficient to copy the files to a flash drive or other interim media and then paste it into the new destination `/home/username`.

Make sure that you use a POSIX-compatible file system like `ext4`.

Because your user should be the owner of the home folder and its contents, you may need to run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME` after copying the files.

Comment: The  flash drive should not be formatted in NTFS, otherwise you will lose meta information, like file permissions.

Comment: Let the environment fill in the values.